# Bootstrap DateTimePicker is not showing the current date

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I used Bootstrap datetimepicker inside Bootstrap modal. It shows the calendar with out showing the current date. 
[DateTimePicker Calandar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUxC1.png)
Can someone help, how I can be able to show the current date?

Here is the reference

```
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the code

```
<div class='input-group date datepicker'>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Date"></asp:TextBox>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
       $('.datepicker').datepicker();
     });
</script>
```

Comment: Use `useCurrent: true` in option. for more info read [here](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#usecurrent)

Comment: There is also a typo in the code 'placeholder=Date"' is missing a quote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

todayHighlight: true option setting works, Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

To Use current date set   `Default: true`

Comment: Tested default: true and it breaks code

Answer (score -1):

useCurrent

`Default: true`

Check this : http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#usecurrent